# Using Python how to determine if a set of data is already in memory

Tags: python, memory, heap

I'm looking into creating heaps and there are two options given. The base case for use of the module is as follows:

```
import heapq
from heapq_showtree import show_tree
from heapq_heapdata import data
heap = []
print('random :', data)
print()

for n in data:
    print('add {:>3}:'.format(n))
    heapq.heappush(heap, n)
    show_tree(heap)
```

The guide then goes on to say that:

> If the data is already in memory, it is more efficient to use `heapq.heapify()` to rearrange

What does that mean? How do I determine if the data is already stored in memory?

Comment: It means that if you already happen to have a list, then using `heapify` directly on that list is more efficient than using that for-loop.

Comment: What guide? You're not looking at the heapq docs.

Comment: Yeah, that documentation is not well written.  Its not if the data is "in memory."  It's "if you already have a Python list then ..."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Heck, if you don't have a list, it's still more efficient to build one and call `heapify` than it is to `heappush` items one at a time. `heappush` is good for incrementally modifying a heap, not for initial heap construction.